# Expected value of a distribution with hazard rate is $k/x$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $F$ be a cdf and $f$ its pdf, such that

$\frac{f(x)}{1-F(x)}=\frac{k}{x}$, where $k>1$ is a constant.

I want to find a lower bound for the expected value of a random variable distributed according to $F$.

Is there a way to do so? Even better, is it possible to recover the distribution $F$?

Answer (score 1):

If hazard rate is $\frac{k}{x}$ for $x>x_0$ then the distribution is Pareto with pdf 
$$f(x)=\frac{kx_0^k}{x^{k+1}}\mathbb 1_{\{x>x_0\}}$$

Indeed, denote $G(x)=1-F(x)$. Then $f(x)=-G'(x)$ and equality fro hazard rate give 
$$-\frac{G'(x)}{G(x)} = \frac{k}{x}.$$

Solve this differencial equation. 
$$(\ln G(x))' = -\frac{k}{x}$$
$$\ln G(x) = -k\ln x + c$$
$$ G(x) = e^c\,e^{-k\ln x}=\frac{c_1}{x^k}$$
and CDF is $F(x)=1-\frac{c_1}{x^k}$. In order to be a CDF, it should look like this only for $x$ greater then some $x_0>0$. And $G(x_0)=0$. Continuity implies that $c_1=x_0^k$. Finally,
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}1-\frac{x_0^k}{x^k}, & x> x_0 \cr
0, & x\leq x_0 \end{cases}
$$
The expectation for this distribution equals to
$$
\mathbb E[X]=x_0 \frac{k}{k-1}.
$$
Since $x_0>0$ is arbitrary, only zero lower bound is possible.